# Huge Difference in IO and CPU for same query

Tags: sql-server, performance, execution-plan, query-store

I saw that same query got more than two execution plans. Query is included inside procedure which runs once a day every day. All tables in query got from 2000 to 50000 additional records every day. I can not understand huge difference in terms of IO, CPU and duration (below query store screen for IO - logical reads AVG) :

[image]

Plan 113700:

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Sy-Uczky9

Plan 92433:

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rkHq9Mkyq

For me both are similar.

Comment: Those are some pretty complex queries, with both missing indexes and plan-affecting conversions.  You can start to clean those up, but if you're happy with a plan you can force it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-query-store-force-plan-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Thank you. Do you know If we force plan in query store it will still be effective after a server restart ?

Comment: In addition to David's point, you may need to look at tuning the underlying queries. There are a lot of tables being joined, etc. What I typically do when I have a plan like that is to start breaking down the query into bite size peaces to see which part is the "slow" part, and tune that section. While your query appears to be a single select, I suspect it's a view. Break open the view and see what it's doing.